# Using clearvars correctly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

The function `clearvars` has the instructions presented [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html).

So say I have a set of variables,

```
 a, b, c, d
```

and I want to clear these variables except for **d** I should be able to do this:

```
clearvars * -except d
```

but I get the following error:

```
 clearvars * -except d
                |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Your edit has such a smart arse comment. I love it ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works: `clearvars '*' -except d`

Matlab must have a problem converting `*` into a string when it's on its own. It's fine with both `a*` and `*a`, but not `*`.

Also, this works:

```
clearvars('*', '-except', 'd')
```

Answer (score 5):

The `*` character is not needed.

Comment: but the example on the page says this: clearvars a* -except -regexp a$ is an example of a working system, so why doesn't the star work?

Comment: In that case, `*` acts as a wildcard to match any variables starting with `a`.  Try making some variables like `aa = 1; ab = 2; ac = 3`, then use something like `clearvars a* -except ab` to see how it works.

Comment: Yep i understand how it works, but usually the star indicates everything. I guess its just a matlab quirk as to why the star by itself doesn't work.